# How can i best update an icon on a child component in react-native?

Tags: reactjs, react-native

I have a small app in react-native.  The parent screen component makes an API call and uses the results of that API call to update the parent state "results" variable (so this.state.results will contain "n" objects).  In the render method of the parent, I am using this.state.results.map to add child components onto the screen.  Each child component takes the form of a card.  Each card has a Favorite icon which is meant to be clickable and when favorite is true, the icon is green and when its false, the icon is grey.

My problem comes in when on the event handler for the icon click.  I could do this either by passing in the callback from the parent to the child and executing in the parent or I could do it in the child component which is how I have it currently.

The event handler makes another API call back to the server to update the user record to add the new favorite.  This part works fine as well, however, what I have yet to work out, is how to get the icon to update from grey to green when it becomes favorite or from green to grey when it is clicked to "un-favorite".  I'm updating the server fine with my API call but I can't quite work out how to update the icon on the child component.  I have tried to use local state on the card component with some very mixed results and I can't quite work out how to update the parent component state.  I can trigger an event handler on the parent and i can pass in some arguments from the child but I'm not quite certain how I can update the parent state or if that will even update the child component with the icon if I do that.

Would appreciate the experience of someone who's worked through this sort of issue before.

Thanks.

Comment: I would pass the api call function to child but that doesn’t really matter. When you change an item’s favorite state on the api you should update the this.state.results by fetching the results again. Or api could just return all the results after favorite action. Then child will update the icon color if its props has changed. And remember to add ‘key’ prop to every card component. This is important. Or use a FlatList with ‘keyExtractor’ prop.

Comment: As @negative_zero has suggested, try using a FlatList. Can you share a snippet of what you've done so far?

Comment: So i think i've solved my issue.  I have the the child component doing a callback to the parent component which makes the API call to update the server to set the favorite setting to true and then i'm re-querying the server to get the current values which updates state and consequently updates the icon.  This works but its a little slow.  I'm currently working to put in the activity indicator.